# mounted directory on host does not work or access docker container

Tags: linux, docker, centos, mount, nfs

my docker version

$ docker -v

```
Docker version 1.7.1, build 786b29d
```

host mounted some directory on boot.

```
$ cat /etc/rc.d/rc.local 
mount -t nfs -o nolock db:/A /usr/local/B/C


[root@web8 ~]# df -h

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2        24G  1.1G   22G   5% /
tmpfs           3.9G  148K  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1       190M   71M  109M  40% /boot
/dev/sda7       9.5G  1.2G  7.9G  13% /tmp
/dev/sda3        20G  6.1G   13G  34% /usr
/dev/sda8        51G   16G   33G  32% /usr/local
/dev/sda6        15G  3.8G  9.9G  28% /var
db:/A       974G   74G  850G   8% /usr/local/B/C
```

when run container

```
$ docker run -i -t \
--name testWeb
--expose 80 \
-v /usr/local/B:/usr/local/B \
TestOS /bin/bash -c '/entrypoint.sh'
```

into container

```
$ docker exec -i -t testWeb /bin/bash


$ cd /usr/local/B/C
```

empty

```
$ ls
```

how to solve my problem ? plz..

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: The version of docker that you are using is far out of date, and should not be used. There have been numerous security fixes on newer versions that have not been back ported to this old version.